# C# problem with multi-clients server application

Tags: c#, multithreading, client-server, data-transfer

I have a server application and a client application. 
I'm using socket to communicate between server and client. Everything works fine if there's only one client connect: uploading, downloading all work well.

But if there's another client connect (I start the client application again, which means there're 2 client apps and 1 server app running on my computer), my server starts to mess up: server doesn't receive file upload from client, client couldn't download from server.

In server code, I already used multithreading for each client connection so I can't figure out the problem. Here is my server code:

```
    private void ServerForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {

                //...
                Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForPeers));
                th.Start();
            }

    public void ListenForPeers()
            {
                    serversocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                    serversocket.Blocking = true;
                    IPHostEntry IPHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(server);
                    string[] aliases = IPHost.Aliases;
                    IPAddress[] addr = IPHost.AddressList;
                    IPEndPoint ipepServer = new IPEndPoint(addr[0], 8090);
                    serversocket.Bind(ipepServer);
                    serversocket.Listen(-1);
                    while (true)
                    {
                        clientsock = serversocket.Accept();
                        if (clientsock.Connected)
                        {
                            total_clients_connected++;
                            AppendText("Client connected...");
                            Thread tc = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listenclient));
                            tc.Start();
                        }
             }


    void listenclient()
        {
             // start communication
        }
```

Is there something wrong with my server code that makes it unable to become a multi-clients server system? Help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing it on low level? Why not use WCF?

Comment: I will look into it cuz I'm just new to programming. Anyway my problem is fixed now thanks to chezyz525. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've defined your clientSocket as a global variable to be used by all server threads, instead you want it to be a local reference for each thread.  You can do this with a ParameterizedThreadStart:

```
public void listenForPeers()
{
  //Setup the server socket

  while(true){
    Socket newClient = serverSock.Accept();
    if(newClient.Connected){
      Thread tc = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(listenclient));
      tc.start(newClient);
    }
  }
}

void listenclient(object clientSockObj)
{
  Socket clientSock = (Socket)clientSockObj;

  //communication to client via clientSock.
}
```

Comment: Yes!! Thanks a lot chezy525. It works perfectly!! All uploading, downloading... with 2 and 3 clients, all work fine. Thanks again, chezy525, you make my day :).

Comment: No problem.  The key issue here is thread safety.  With any multi-threaded program you need to be very careful with global variables, using them only for static or shared data.  And then being wary of any possible race conditions, or other potential pitfalls... speaking of which you should really lock you're reads/writes to the client counter variable.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're setting your socket's Blocking property to true.  This will block any requests until the previous ones finish...

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.blocking(VS.80).aspx

> If you are in blocking mode, and you
>   make a method call which does not
>   complete immediately, your application
>   will block execution until the
>   requested operation completes. If you
>   want execution to continue even though
>   the requested operation is not
>   complete, change the Blocking property
>   to false. The Blocking property has no
>   effect on asynchronous methods. If you
>   are sending and receiving data
>   asynchronously and want to block
>   execution, use the ManualResetEvent
>   class.

You might want to reconsider doing it this way, and instead use WCF or maybe a web service for uploading the files...  it'll be a lot easier, and IIS will handle the threading for you.  It's pretty easy to write a web service to upload a file...

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/UploadwithCSharpWS05032007121259PM/UploadwithCSharpWS.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also thought of the blocking part but when 2nd client connected, it communicated with server (sending username/password, checking if it's admin or employee connects, sending/receiving download/upload requests...) So it changed my mind about the blocking part.I prefer using socket because there're some problems with using WS and connecting to database, and checking authentication... If the blocking part is the problem then is there anyway to fix this? I don't understand the msdn solution much... Again, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'd give @chezy525' answer a try...  and post back if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const int noOfClients = 5;

for(int i=0;i<noOfClients;i++)
{
  Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForPeers));
  th.Start();
}
```